# How to pass operators like "and", "or", "xor" in browser url

Tags: php

I have send data through ajax using these words "and","or","xor" after that pass numeric value it gives page not found error.

ajax_saveBooking.php?edit_course=4596&edit_note=xor+2&booking_date=2015-02-05&edit_booking_id=301

check edit_note=xor+2 argument when I removed 2 its working fine.

Also I have noticed when I used windows server its working fine but when I used Linux server it give page not found error. Please some one help me to fix this problem

Comment: What kind of code is executed in `ajax_saveBooking.php`? You probably need to find that out, otherwise we cannot help much.

Comment: Actually, I have used ajax to save a form. When I entered some operators under description field it give 404 page not found error. check below: &edit_note=xor+2

Comment: Check the case of your filename - is it `ajax_saveBooking.php` or `ajax_savebooking.php` etc? The case sensitivity of files is one of the differences between Windows and Linux.

Comment: I have entered correct file name ajax_saveBooking.php. It works when I delete numeric value under this argument "&edit_note=xor+2"

Comment: I suspect that, part of, the problem is the plus is being translated (unescaped) to a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is characteristic of a web application firewall trying (in a misguided way) to block SQL injection.  Contact your web host for details.

Comment: Yes, the problem is fixed. Web hosting provider enabled firewall protection. So, that's why these operator's not pass in query string. Thanks @duskwuff